# Using non-standard arguments in defining functions

Tags: function-construction, arguments

I am trying to define a function that has a non-standard argument (i.e, UnderBar[a]_) instead of standard arguments like English or Latin Letters:
Here is my example:

```
f[UnderBar[a]_]:=UnderBar[a]^2
```

This does not work though. A solution is appreciated.

Comment: `f[UnderBar[a_]] := UnderBar[a]^2`? I think you just misplaced your `Blank`. Or is that not the functionality you want?

Comment: @ItaiSeggev : f[a: UnderBar[a]] := a^2 works perfectly fine. Out of curiosity, how can I keep UnderBar[a] in the Right Hand Side?

Comment: @MarcoB : Can you copy the right function here?

Comment: @Vahidn What do you mean? I included my suggestion in my previous comment (note the change in position of the underscore).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. I got it.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because it had a typo in it.  It should have been `f[a: UnderBar[_]] := a^2 `. If you wish to explicitly keep `a` on the RHS, just use the form suggested by @MarcoB.  He binds `a` to the variable inside the `UnderBar`.  My form binds it to the whole `UnderBar` expression.